# How to know what is the second greatest number (of 3 numbers)? (C)

Tags: c

I want to know the "greatest", "greatest2", and "smallest" numbers. What I wrote doesn't work. Not even sure why. How can I fix this and If I had more numbers, is there a better option? Thanks in advance. (l1,l2,l3 would be the sides of a triangle) (also, it's in C)

```
greatest=l1;
    if(greatest<l2){
        greatest=l2;
    }if(greatest<l3){
        greatest=l3;
    }

    greatest2=l1;
    if(greatest2<l2&&l2<greatest){
        greatest2=l2;
    }if(greatest2<l3&&l3<greatest){
        greatest2=l3;
    }

    smallest=l1;
    if(smallest>l2){
        smallest=l2;
    }if(smallest>l3){  //had a mistake here, instead of > I had <
        smallest=l3;
```

I can mention that I don't really know much, but any advice is highly appreciated

Comment: A couple of nested ternary operators?  Use one to pick out that largest of two inputs, the other to pick the smallest of that result and the third input number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your assumption `greatest2=l1;` is incorrect if `l1` is the second biggest.
The correct code should be

```
if (l1 != greatest)
    greatest2 = l1;
else
    greatest2 = l2;
```

If you have an array of numbers:
You can do it in 1 loop: if you find a new maximum, the old maximum is the new second maximum, else if it is larger than the second, it is the new second maximum.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int a[] = {12,10,15,17,18,14,15,20};
    int max = a[0], second = a[0];
    unsigned size = sizeof a / sizeof a[0];
    if (size <= 1) //there would be no second number
        return -1;
    for (unsigned i = 1; i < size; i++)
    {
        if (a[i] >= max)
        {
            second = max;
            max = a[i];
        }
        else if (a[i] > second)
        {
            second = a[i];
        }
    }
    printf("max: %d, second: %d\n", max, second);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That (top part) plus correcting a mistake I made did it. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Short and sweet:

```
greatest = l1 > l2 ? l1 > l3 ? l1 : l3 : l2 > l3 ? l2 : l3;
smallest = l1 < l2 ? l1 < l3 ? l1 : l3 : l2 < l3 ? l2 : l3;
middle = greatest == l1 ? (smallest == l2 ? l3 : l2) : greatest == l2 ? (smallest == l3 ? l1 : l3) : l2;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you had 3 numbers you can use:

```
if(a>c)
swap(a,c)

if (a > b)
swap(a, b)

//Now the smallest element is the first one. 

if (b > c)
swap(b, c);
//sorted
```

If you had much more number than 3:

C/C++ standard library  contains qsort function.

This is not the best quick sort implementation in the world but it fast enough and VERY EASY to be used... the formal syntax of qsort is:

qsort(,,sizeof(),compare_function);

```
int arr[] = {3,5,8};

qsort(values, 3, sizeof(int), cmpfunc);


for( n = 0 ; n < 3; n++ ) 
{   
   printf("%d ", values[n]);
}
```

Comment: A sort on three numbers?

Comment: Author asked how to sort 3 numbers but also a better option to sort more numbers than 3

Comment: He didn't ask how to sort them; he asked which was biggest, which was smallest, and which was in the middle. It's a subtle but important difference. Sorting 3 numbers is hugely wasteful. Just calling `qsort` probably takes more processor time than calculating the answer with `if` statements.

Comment: So if he had 1000 numbers would you still suggest to use `if` statements? This answer is almost right (Didn't say how to get the greatests and the smalles though). And OP doesn't want the number in the middle he wants the 2 greatest numbers and the smallest. Sorting is the best approach

Comment: @Mr.E No, of course 1000 is a different case. This is at the very heart of sorting theory. Sorting small sets such as 3 numbers is wasteful and should never be done. Consult Knuth.

Answer (score 0):

Put the numbers in a list(vector) and sort them.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/

Once they are in order, it is trivial to pick out the biggest, 2nd biggest, etc.

Comment: C/C++ are used pretty synonymous these days.  I hope you down vote the qsort suggestion too :)

Comment: @mjr C doesn't provide vectors natively, so now he has to write an entire set of vector functions or find a library just to choose three numbers.